laravel model is not returning object even though its loaded from database
I have Client<->Address relation defined in laravel as below
class Client extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $keyType = 'string';

    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'location',
        'status',
    ];

    public function address()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ClientAddress::class);
    }
}

class ClientAddress extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;
    
    protected $keyType = 'string';

    public $incrementing = false;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'street',
        'zip',
    ];

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }
}

I am able to save it in database.
When I read it like below and print I get address
public function getAddress(Request $request)
    {
        $client=Client::with('address')->find($request->id);
        Log::info($client);
        Log::info($client->address);
        return ClientAddressResource::make($client->address);
    }

first log value is :

[2024-06-22 10:39:15] local.INFO: {"id":"12cf02ff-fff7-4b8d-8eb5-64d5328afc8b","name":"Client With address","location":"Delhi","status":"OK","address":{"id":"0b956710-3681-4042-96c2-877345167c46","street":"str1","street2":"str2","city":"some city","state":"stt","country":"India","zip":"1234","client_id":"12cf02ff-fff7-4b8d-8eb5-64d5328afc8b"},"created_at":"2024-06-20T21:14:50.000000Z","updated_at":"2024-06-20T21:14:50.000000Z"}

second log is empty

[2024-06-22 10:39:15] local.INFO:

last line gives error

[2024-06-22 10:39:15] local.ERROR: Attempt to read property "street" on null {"userId":"981cfca3-46ed-47a7-91df-5424b563e723","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Attempt to read property "street" on null at .....

I tried a lot of google, and SO answers but none talks about reading of object and convert to json.
migrations:
Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('location');
            $table->string('status');
     });

        Schema::create('client_addresses', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->string('street');
            $table->string('zip');
            $table->foreignUuid('client_id')->constrained();
        });


The error you are getting might be of the relationship is not properly loaded.Check it again

Can you please share your both migrations file as well?

You're using a custom primary key, so I assume it's not handled properly. Check the data in the tables and how you fill the primary and foreign keys, ensure also to manage porperly UUID and ULID Keys

@Subha, I added the migrations as well, not sure what do you mean by not properly loaded. I did what is documented.

also, as you can see in first log line, address is getting printed, so it is already there in object

@R.S, If I am not wrong then the problem resides in eager-loading since your code seems to me correct.If this is the case then it is conceptually very good question.

@R.S , I have posted my answer. Please check and let me know.

Though I am not sure but there might be a possibility that issue resides in Eager loading.
I know this sometimes causes issue.
Eager loading :-
It is a concept in which when retrieving records, you get all the needed items together with all related items at the same time.
In this case though you have fetched record of client successfully the related record of client_addresses might not be fetched properly.
So I think You should try Lazy loading to check if it is working.
So try this code.
$client = Client::find($request->id);

$client_address = $client->address ; // one-to-one relationship

foreach($client->address as $add )   //one-to-many relationship
{
   ......
}

Try this and let me know if it is working.

I tried this as well, still same result.

though when I do $client->address()->first() it works

Okay that means your problem solved?

Does client has many address or a single address in DB??

single, its hasOne relation. Problem is solved for this case where I am returning only ClientAddressResource but I am stuck again when returning ClientResource, there also I want to fill address inside ClientResource class toArray, there also I am not able to get the record, might have to use the first() again.

By model defination it was single. But I think there might be more than one related model however inserted in the DB cz if in DB there was one related model the  $client->adrress would have worked. If $client->adress() ->first() is working then high chances that there is multiple address for same client_id.Can you please check and let me know so that I can understand what the actual issue was. But it is confirmed that lazy loading worked in this case.

there was only one record in the table,  also as in log it is printing, related address is loaded in memory already.

this is not a solution because the same resource lazily loads and returns address even when I dont load model with child

@R.S, As @TUPKAP mentioned I think you should import use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUuids; to both of your model since you are using UUID as your primary-key. Check the link for detailed info https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#uuid-and-ulid-keys
